# Как найти сумму цифр многозначного числа рекурсией?

Tags: javascript

Задача: написать функцию, аргументом которой является число(может быть как дробным так и целым), а результатом - сумма всех цифр

```
сal(123) = 1+2+3 = 6
cal(123.45) = 1+2+3+4+5 = 15
```

Загвоздка в том что нельзя использовать никаких методов, циклов. Только рекурсия. Может есть кто знает решение?

Comment: А это точно JavaScript? Можете своими словами описать условие задачи и её предполагаемый ответ?

Comment: Да, конечно. Аргументом является число(может быть как дробным так и целым), при запуске функции должно вернуть сумму всех чисел(сal(123) = 1+2+3), условием решения является то что нельзя использовать никаких методов и циклов(for, reduce и все что есть в js и вызывается с помощью ()).

Comment: Я что-то не могу себе представить решение без скобок…

Answer (score 1):

для вызова рекурсии все равно использованы скобки...

```js
let cal = a => {
    // преобразуем входной аргумент в массив символов если это число
    a = a > 0 ? [...a + ''] : a;

    // приводим к числу последний символ массива или берем 0 если символ не приводится к числу 
    let b = + a[a.length - 1] || 0; 

    // складываем число с результатом вызова этой же функции, 
    // но уже с массивом без последнего символа, пока массив содержит символы
    return a ? b + cal(--a.length ? a : 0) : 0;
}

console.log(cal(123.45));
```

Comment: Хе-хе, а моя функция на строках не падает...

Comment: @SergeyNudnov :) ну это не сложно добавить, но я почему-то не стал рассматривать такую возможность на ночь глядя. меня больше заинтересовало отсутствие скобок при вызове рекурсии..

Comment: У Вас более лаконичный код, хотя и не будет работать на IE из-за `...`. А вот с рекурсией... Жаль, что нету перезагрузки операторов.

Comment: @SergeyNudnov у меня такое ощущение что можно формально соблюсти оригинальное условие автора вообще не использовать скобки

Comment: @SergeyNudnov я еще подсократил код + было замечено что отрицательное число вернет 0, но в вопросе про это тоже ничего нет

Answer (score 1):

А ларчик просто открывался...

```js
console.log(cal(123.45))
console.log(cal())
console.log(cal('abcd'))
console.log(cal('abcd123.45'))

function cal(value, index=0) {
    var result = 0;
    var value_text = value + ""; //преобразуем в строку
    var skip = index === value_text.length; //признак пропуска вычислений

    var digit_text = skip? "." : value_text[index]; //очередная цифра в виде строки
    index += 1;

    //result += digit_text >= '0' && digit_text <= '9'? digit_text - '0' : 0;
    //Не могу удержаться не использовать красивое преобразование от @Stranger in the Q...
    result += + digit_text || 0; 

    result += skip? 0 : cal(value_text, index); //рекурсия для следующего индекса
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если задача именно в рекурсии, то могу предложить такой алгоритм:

```
Если входной параметр - 0, то вернуть 0.
Если входной параметр - дробное число > 1, то результат = cal(целая часть)+cal(дробная часть).
Если входной параметр - целое число, то результат = остаток от деления на 10 + cal(целая часть от деления на десять).
Если входной параметр - дробное число от 0 до 1 (не включительно), то результат = целая часть от умножения на 10 + cal(дробная часть от умножения на десять).
```