# Как найти сумму цифр многозначного числа без циклов, массивов и строк?

Tags: java, python, алгоритм

Как найти сумму цифр многозначного числа без использования условных и циклических конструкций, массивов, строковых данных и операции над ними?

Comment: Остаток от деления на 10 - последняя цифра в числе. В связке с циклом даст нужный результат.

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych по условию циклы использовать нельзя.
Только при помощи базовых операторов

Comment: Вы уверены, что Java, а не JavaScript? А то пробегало такое тут уже недавно. В любом случае, посмотрите ответы на данный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968570)

Comment: *можно ли найти сумму цифр многозначного числа без использования условных и циклических конструкций, массивов, строковых данных и операции над ними ?* Нет. Проверка на окончание работы не может быть выполнена без "условной конструкции".

Comment: @SergeyNudnov да, по java

Comment: @Akina, пожалуй, можно. В Java же вроде нет встроенной длинной арифметики? Значит, число знаков в числе ограничено, и можно просто фиксированное число раз повторить деление на 10 и суммирование остатка. Последние итерации скорее всего отработают вхолостую (число превратится в 0 раньше), но тут уж ничего не поделаешь. :)

Comment: @Yaant Аналогично - в задании не указано, что под "многозначным" понимается число встроенного типа, а не подключаемый тип из библиотеки длинной арифметики...

Comment: @Akina Бритва Оккама протестует. :) А то так можно дойти и до предположения, что в этой условной библиотеке заодно окажется и функция для подсчета искомой суммы. :)

Comment: @Akina Думаю, можно ограничиться длинной int

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно 9 или 18 (для 64 бит) раз написать

```
sum += value % 10;
value /= 10;
```

Это безусловный способ (однако он использует наше знание о природе целых чисел).

Иначе прямым или косвенным образом будут использованы операторы сравнения для проверки окончания работы.

Comment: А как можно найти произведение?
Как обойти умножение на 0 ?

Comment: Какое произведение? Об этом ведь речи не было.

Comment: Это уже из любопытства

Comment: Ведущие нули без проверок не отсеешь

Answer (score 6):

Так как в тегах есть Python, привожу решение для него, Java не занимаюсь, так что нет компилятора под рукой, чтобы сделать и протестировать то же под Java.

Основной принцип - рекурсия с выходом по исключению, вместо условного оператора

```
def sum_digits(value):
    try:
        _ = 1 / value
    except:
        return 0
    digit = value % 10
    return digit + sum_digits(int(value/10))

print(sum_digits(245))
```

Answer (score 3):

Ответом стала рекурсия

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by German Bogdanov on 08.05.2019.
*/
public class Task2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input number: ");
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(sumDigits(number));
        System.out.println(productDigits(number));
    }


    public static int sumDigits(int i) {
        return i == 0 ? 0 : i % 10 + sumDigits(i / 10);
    }
    public static int productDigits(int i) {
        return i == 0 ? 1 : i % 10 * productDigits(i / 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: **без использования условных конструкций** - а `i == 0 ?` - это что?

Comment: @SergeyNudnov Понятно
Думал что только switch case и if else это условные
Тогда вопрос остался открыт

Comment: В любой экскурсии должно быть условие выхода из нее... без этого никак